# Encrypting Contact.Name when using OWASP

Tags: apex, managed-package, security, encryption, platform-encryption

We are looking into encrypting a contact.name field in an org that has OWASP installed. When trying to encrypt the field, we get the following error:

> Apex Class: testAccessController, line 137, column 13: encrypted field
>   'LastName' cannot be filtered in a query call

I investigated and found that testAccessController is a class in OWASP library, which is a standard security library. I'd like to know if there is any way to work around this? We cannot uninstall owasp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are working with our partners to help them be encryption ready, by avoiding to explicitly filter on encryptable fields. It is particularly challenging for the standard fields that can be used by many packages.

We honestly don't yet have a great answer, this is an area we're focusing on, specially by finding ways to give back more features on encrypted fields (forward looking statement).